# How are JS scripts correctly encoded to run as GET in URL

Tags: javascript, php, url

I'm doing a XSS test and already have a working JS solution, however, I'm a little bit on the wrong track on how scripts need to be encoded and escaped correctly to run in the browsers as expected.

Let's assume I have found a vulnerability where `XSS` is to be replaced with JS code:

```
http://vulnerablewebsite.net/?search=<script>XSS</script>
```

Obviously, a simple `<script>alert(1);<script>` will work fine.
But what about a more complex script like:

```
var url = document.body.outerHTML.match(/http:\/\/blabla\.net\/\?token=([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])*/)[0];
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url);
request.setRequestHeader("X-Test","test1");
```

I understand that `"` and `'` need to be escaped in order not to run into a PHP Syntax error, but what about newline characters, spaces etc.?

Comment: Dont allow users to insert HTML and if they do somehow - Just [strip the tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) out of them!

Comment: Did you read the question?
It is not how to prevent XSS.

Comment: `strip_tags()` is by the way NOT a secure way to prevent cross site scripting.